# Access denied error when deploying artifact to Archiva remote repo

Tags: maven-3, archiva

I am trying to deploy project artifact into Archiva remote repository but keeps getting this error:

**Error Message:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-deploy) @ mavenandroidapplication ---
Downloading: http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/stm/idg/android/mavenandroidapplication/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/stm/idg/android/mavenandroidapplication/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mavenandroidapplication-1.0-20131105.013101-1.apk
Uploading: http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/stm/idg/android/mavenandroidapplication/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mavenandroidapplication-1.0-20131105.013101-1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.707s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 05 09:31:01 SGT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/39M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project mavenandroidapplication: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.stm.idg.android:mavenandroidapplication:apk:1.0-20131105.013101-1 from/to archiva.snapshots (http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/): Access denied to http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/stm/idg/android/mavenandroidapplication/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mavenandroidapplication-1.0-20131105.013101-1.apk. Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

I am using **Maven 3.0.5**, **Archiva 1.3.6**, **Android Development Kit**. This is a maven project and I execute via *Run As --> Maven build --> (Goals) deploy*.

Below are the configurations:

**Settings.xml**
Note:

```
    <server>
      <id>archiva.internal</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>123</password>
    </server>
```

**Pom.xml**

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>archiva.internal</id>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>archiva.snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.10.29:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: do you have issues when using command line instead of your ide?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1.) Ensure that you have all your servers listed in your Maven settings.xml.  This gets me sometimes.

2.) Ensure that your snapshot repo id matches the repo id defined within Archiva.

3.) Ensure that you have access to the snapshots repo, even as admin.  Permissions can be revoked.

4.) Ensure that you have the right password.

5.) I've had a restart of Archiva fix this problem before.

6.) And, finally, ensure that you have the following settings.xml config in place.  This solution doesn't quite fit your scenario, but it's good to list nonetheless.  The following config will allow you to deploy snapshots to a custom snapshots repo that's part of a repository group (i.e. - a snapshots repo for a particular team):

```
<mirror>
    <id><repo_group_id></id>
    <mirrorOf>*, !<team_snapshot_repo_id></mirrorOf>
    <name>My Team's Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://<HOST>:<PORT>/archiva/repository/<repo_group_id>/</url>
</mirror>
```